# Random number generation with random operators

Tags: android, random

I am new to android development and currently working on a simple app which, among other things, needs to generate random numbers with random operators (+, -, *, /) every time. I have a "generate" button which is supposed to give different questions every time it is pressed. I know how to generate random numbers, but I don't know how to generate the random operators so that the question is different every time. I tried using a switch statement but not successful so far (or I'm missing code in it). Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Here is the code i have thus far:

private void goGenerate() {

```
    num1 = (int)(Math.random()*10) + 1;
    num2 = (int)(Math.random()*10) + 1;
    generate();
}

private void generate() {
    StringBuilder equation = new StringBuilder();
    goGenerate();

    operator = (int)(Math.random() *4 ) + 1;

    equation.append(num1);
    if(operator == 1) {
        equation.append("+");
        result = num1 + num2;
    }
    else if(operator == 2) {
        equation.append("-");
        result = num1-num2;
    }
    else if(operator == 3) {
        equation.append("*");
        result = num1 * num2;
    }
    else if(operator == 4) {
        equation.append("/");
        while((num1 % num2 != 0) && (num1 < num2)) {
            generate();
        }
        result = num1 / num2;
    }

    textViewOperation.setText(operator);
```

Comment: Please post the code what you've already tried so we can help you with your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make two random routines, one for your number and one, restricted to 0-3, where you associate each of the possible numbers (0 to 3) to an operator. Then it's done. Good luck.

**EDIT (this works):**

```
int operator, num1, num2, result;
StringBuilder equation;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    final TextView tv1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv1);
    tv1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            generate();
            tv1.setText(String.valueOf(result));
        }
    });

}



private Integer generate() {

    equation = new StringBuilder();
    num1 = (int)(Math.random()*10) + 1;
    num2 = (int)(Math.random()*10) + 1;

    operator = new Random().nextInt(4);

    equation.append(num1);
    if (operator == 1) {
        equation.append("+");
        result = num1 + num2;
    } else if (operator == 2) {
        equation.append("-");
        result = num1 - num2;
    } else if (operator == 3) {
        equation.append("*");
        result = num1 * num2;
    } else if (operator == 4) {
        equation.append("/");
        while ((num1 % num2 != 0) && (num1 < num2)) {
            generate();
        }
        result = num1 / num2;
    }
    return result;
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I understand what you're saying. I am not sure how I can associate the number to the operator though.

Comment: if (random_num == 1) my_operator = "/"; (and so on)

Comment: @LukasA. if you prefer edit your answer, post your code and I will help you to implement this.

Comment: I put the code in my initial question. not sure how to add it in comments as I run out of characters?:S

Comment: Nice: first of all I would use `int operator = new Random().nextInt(4);` (I don't know if with the same results of your method). Well, I think it's all. Have you got what you wanted?

Comment: No, still no luck. app crashes.

Comment: Hi, the code you posted works, but it generates one integer. What I am trying to do is generate random equations with random numbers every time. Thanks you, however, for trying to help.

Comment: My code randomizes new numbers and operators every time you tap on TextView, have you tried? After tapped, TextView shows the final result of the random operation made by the randomized numbers. Don't you think, after all of this, you can handle and adapt the code for your use, with your specific details? If you think so, please, check my answer as the correct one. Thank you. Glad if i was anyway helpful.

Comment: @LukasA. excuse me, correct me if I am wrong: you've asked how to create random operators (... **I don't know how to generate the random operators** ...). My first answer, clean and clear, right after your question, was already correct and nice. There I said everything you wanted and needed ( **Make two random routines, one for your number and one, restricted to 0-3, where you associate each of the possible numbers (0 to 3) to an operator** ). You can confirm this with a simple Toast or Log.d, for example. Later, as a plus, I tried to solve all your problems, but seems I failed. Yet (continue)

Comment: Yet I insist: the question you've done I've already answered for you. If mine or your routines doesn't led you to make all your app running (maybe because your poor explanation or coding habilities), this is another problem(s). You asked some precise question: how do I random four operators. I answered for you, agree? So please, be kind, welcome to StackOverflow, and mark (at the right of my answer) my answer as the correct one because it is actually the correct one. No need to say thank you, but recognize my efforts and time in your benefit, ok? Thank you and God Bless.